# How to use google or microsoft translator api with python to translate text files?

Tags: python, text, translation

I would like to automatically pre-translate a bunch of text files that I have on my hard disk. Is there a way to do this with python. I already got the google translate api key and I would like to use that.
The files I have include some XML code, however, I first would like to get the translator to work with some plain text files.
One text file might look like this:

```
Hello, my name is Stefan. I live in Germany and my hobbies are tennis, walking and reading.
```

My question now is how to read in the text file and automatically translate it from English to German.

I looked around the web for quite a while but I couldn't find a solution to my problem.

Any direct help or linkage to another post/website is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the google translate API?

Comment: consider using this python library: https://github.com/nidhaloff/deep_translator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to look at [a parse question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627609/check-if-page-contains-specific-word/10632097#10632097) which is Perl not Python, this is part of a program that parses HTML to extract strings before sending them to the Bing translator.  You'll need to do something like that with the XML probably via [a Python parsing library](http://docs.python.org/library/pyexpat.html).

Then you call the translator service on the string:

```
   # minor adjustment for simplified chinese....
    my $call_language = $language;
    $call_language =~ s/zh/zh-CHS/;

    # microsoft application id for translator....
    my $appId = 'blablabla';
    my $url =
"http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?appId=$appId&text=$text&from=en&to=$call_language";

    ###my $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=<my-key>&q=$text%20world&source=en&target=$language" ;
    # Create a request
    my $req = HTTP::Request->new( GET => $url );

    # Pass request to the user agent and get a response back
    my $res = $ua->request($req);

    #sleep 2 ;
    # Check the outcome of the response
    if ( $res->is_success ) {
        $content = $res->content;
```

Again that's Perl but it gives you the idea, I hope...

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Translate API](https://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html) is now a pay service only, probably because a lot of people were trolling huge amounts of data off through it.  Effectively it's a RESTful API, which means you use standard url and json tools to produce a query in HTTP and then hand that to the API as a GET and then you'll receive back a json object with your translation.  Effectively you'd read in your source file, assemble it into a query, send the HTTP GET of yout query to Google, then parse and use the response.